# Grub install failed with efi64 deepin

Tags: boot, grub, deepin

I was trying to install Deepin alongside windows 10 on acer vx5, and I got this log

> p grub-efi-amd64-signed(1.67+1.65+2.02~beta2)...
>   Processing triggers for man-db(2.7.6.1-2) .. 
>   Running in chroot, ignoring request. 
>   Installing for x86_64-efi platform. 
>   grub-install.real: error: cannot open `/boot/efi/EFI/deepin/shimx64.efi':input/output error. 
>   !! Error: grub-install failed with efi deepin
>   Hook failed: "02_setup_bootloader_x86.job"
>   2.2.13, 15.5, Desktop

Could someone help me please

Comment: Disable Fast Startup in Windows and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I did what Michael said.

Disable fast startup

[Follow these instructions](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)